# Rails map one field in form to two fields in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I've seen a lot of posts about how to map 2 form fields to one model field, but what about mapping 1 form field to provide answers for two (or more) model fields? I have a form for users which gives a field, last_name, for a user. But I want the default password for that user to also be last_name (and I have password_confirmation set up, so that also needs to be last_name). How would I do this?

Form:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :first_name %>
      <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :last_name %>
      <%= f.text_field :last_name, :password, :password_confirmation, 
                        class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.hidden_field :access_level, :value => "Chair" %>

      <%= f.label :Phone %>
      <%= f.text_field :phone_number, :id => "phone", class: 'form-control' %>


      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <%= f.submit "Add Chair", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

user_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      log_in @user
      current_user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Penn Model Congress!"
      redirect_to after_sign_in_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation, :access_level, 
                                   :phone_number)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a `before_validation` [callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) to the `User` model like this:

```
# in app/models/user.rb
before_validation :set_default_password

private
  def set_default_password
    self.password              ||= last_name
    self.password_confirmation ||= last_name
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

If this will be your default and you don't want the user to be able to override it on creation, you could set it on the controller:

View:

```
  <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: 'form-control' %>
```

Controller:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.password = @user.last_name
    @user.password_confirmation = @user.last_name
    if @user.save
       log_in @user
       current_user
       flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Penn Model Congress!"
       redirect_to after_sign_in_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```